# Como puedo solucionar este problema al querer instalar NextJs en mi computadora?

Tags: nextjs

les pido por favor una mano ya que no puedo instalar NextJs en mi computadora, me sale este error en la terminal, Gracias

```
PS C:\Users\FACUNDO> cd C:\Users\FACUNDO\Desktop\NextJs
PS C:\Users\FACUNDO\Desktop\NextJs> npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\FACUNDO\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\FACUNDO\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\FACUNDO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-25T20_48_24_815Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Te fijaste si tienes la carpeta npm en el directorio que te menciona el error y si tienes acceso?

Comment: Seguí los pasos que da la web de nextjs.org, pero me continua el error